# Acer Chromebook 15 CB3-532 full BIOS flash with Ubuntu - No sound

Tags: sound, acer, chromebook

Question relates to: Chromebook 15 Acer model CB3-532 Braswell

With write protect screw removed I performed full BIOS flash.
Replaced write protect screw.
Installed Ubuntu 18.04 as the only operating system.

Laptop is fully operation apart from sound which worked fine before BIOS flash.

I only get Dummy Output.

```
lspci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 35)


aplay -l
karta 1: chtrt5650 [chtrt5650], urządzenie 0: Audio (*) []
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
karta 1: chtrt5650 [chtrt5650], urządzenie 1: Deep-Buffer Audio (*) []
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0


dmesg | grep -i snd
[    3.936277] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    4.444225] cht-bsw-rt5645 cht-bsw-rt5645: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> media-cpu-dai mapping ok
[    4.444267] cht-bsw-rt5645 cht-bsw-rt5645: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> deepbuffer-cpu-dai mapping ok


cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                  HDA Intel PCH at 0xd1314000 irq 315
 1 [chtrt5650      ]: chtrt5650 - chtrt5650
                  GOOGLE-Banon-1.0-Banon
```

Tried so far:

1) set /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf to

options snd-hda-intel model=intel-x58

and

options snd-hda-intel model=auto

and

options snd-hda-intel model=acer

and

options snd-hda-intel model=generic

All options no sound. The last one actually showed HDMI/DisplayPort which might be avenue to follow but I do not know how?

2)  sudo apt-get install oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms following sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily

No change.

3) This seams related: https://github.com/GalliumOS/galliumos-braswell/blob/master/usr/share/alsa/ucm/chtrt5650/chtrt5650.conf This cards shows as 5650 or 5645 I am not sure what this means but following suggestion in the answer I tried:

3.1) downloaded files: github.com/GalliumOS/galliumos-braswell/blob/master/usr/share/… and github.com/GalliumOS/galliumos-braswell/blob/master/usr/share/…

3.2) put them as /usr/share/alsa/ucm/chtrt5650/chtrt5650.conf and /usr/share/alsa/ucm/chtrt5650/HiFi.conf (it was necessary to create chtrt5650 folder as it was not there before)

3.3) Rebooted and: No change. Dummy Output still as the only sound output device.

Comment: With this same laptop I have sound from GalliumOS 3.0 "Braswell" ISO. Did you use stock Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes. Standard install of Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this work for you? https://askubuntu.com/a/1469281/124466

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading that file and the HiFi.conf (https://github.com/GalliumOS/galliumos-braswell/blob/master/usr/share/alsa/ucm/chtrt5650/HiFi.conf) and put them in /usr/share/alsa/ucm/chtrt5650/chtrt5650.conf and /usr/share/alsa/ucm/chtrt5650/HiFi.conf

Comment: Just tried that:
1) downloaded files: https://github.com/GalliumOS/galliumos-braswell/blob/master/usr/share/alsa/ucm/chtrt5650/HiFi.conf and https://github.com/GalliumOS/galliumos-braswell/blob/master/usr/share/alsa/ucm/chtrt5650/chtrt5650.conf
2) put them as /usr/share/alsa/ucm/chtrt5650/chtrt5650.conf and /usr/share/alsa/ucm/chtrt5650/HiFi.conf - it was necessary to create chtrt5650 folder as it was not there before
3) Rebooted and: No change. Dummy Output still as the only sound output device.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `sudo dmesg | grep audio` and see direct firmware load failed error, then try manually copying `sof-bin` firmware to `/lib/firmware/intel/sof-tplg/` folder. See instructions in the answer of [no sound due to error direct firmware load failed for intel/sof-tplg/sof-byt-max98090.tplg](https://askubuntu.com/q/1383051/581796)

*(I am not a developer, just a regular user who encountered a similar problem. )*